# How secure is the phone dial?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

A renown online bank uses a phone dial login system (input your login and password via the phone dial pad). How secure is this communication against MitM and similar attacks?

Considering I recently read how many major telecommunication networks had backdoors in them I am considering this to be bad news.

Comment: It depends on a LOT of things...  Is this POTS? VoIP? Do you know where you local exchange is, and if people can access it without looking suspicious? (i.e., is it just a box on the side of the road that houses a DSLAM and other telco equipment that someone can park a pickup truck next to, don a high-vis vest, set out a traffic cone, and cops would think nothing unusual is happening?)  Are you a probable target of a spear phishing attack or state-level actors? -- In short; not a likely vector as it depends on luck and timing, but telcos aren't know for being secure either...

Comment: It's cellular. I guess the same dangers are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With either rotary or touch tone dialing, if you can hear it then you know what was entered. The ticks/tones are designed to be unambiguous to the recipient.

**So, any listener can recover the digits easily.** Modern attackers will capture and analyze the audio, and the tones were designed to be distinctive to equipment from the 1970s/80s. Some old school phreakers can do it by ear.

**All of the phone networks---POTS (landline), VoIP (internet), and SS7 (cellular)---networks have [serious vulnerabilities](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/voip/paper/2036).** (Note there is a category link on that summary page.)

These security issues are on top of the fact that law enforcement, spy agencies, and corrupt employees/officials can tap the phone lines.

**There is little security, and a lot of it is broken.** Properly encrypted email is far more secure than standard phone calls.

**As a general rule, phone- and SMS-based security processes are inadequate.** They provide the appearance of security, but they will stop only low-effort or unskilled attackers (which, honestly, is the largest group of would-be attackers).

If someone targets you, they can get those credentials relatively easily. **In this case, the biggest risk factor is the likelihood that you will be targeted.** For most people, that risk is quite low.